# unexpected token and special characters during script execution

Tags: shell-script, autosys

I am running several shell scripts via an automation tool(autosys), on a Linux system. The tool creates a temp file while running the jobs, but during the job run the temp file has the special characters shown below on line2. I am not sure why these characters are created.

```
#!  /bin/bash
0Y▒▒
```

Also, when I check my home directory there are multiple  empty files like below, not sure how these files are getting created .

```
^??  :??  ▒    ???  ?    ?▒   ???  ???  ▒??  A??  ▒??     ▒▒   D??  ▒▒   g??  ▒▒                         ?▒   ▒??  ▒▒              U??  ▒▒   ▒▒   x▒   ▒▒
▒??  ▒??  *~?  ?    ???  ???  ???  ???  ▒▒   ▒??  ▒       ▒y?  ▒▒   ▒▒   H▒   ▒▒                         ?▒   ▒??  ▒▒              ▒    +▒   ▒▒   Xz?  [z?
~?   ▒??  +??  ??   ???  ??   ??   ???  ▒▒   ▒??  ▒??     ▒y?  ▒??  ▒▒   ▒??  J▒                         ?▒   ▒??  output          _▒   ▒    v??  ▒y?  ?z?
~??  ]    ?    ??   ??   ??   ???  ???  2??  ▒{?  ▒??     ▒▒   ▒??  ▒y?  ▒    J▒                         ▒    ▒    R??             [▒   ?▒   V??  ?y?  z?
▒    ]}?  ??   ???  ???  ???  ??   ?}?  ▒??  ▒~?  ▒??     b??  ▒??  ▒▒   ▒??  k??                        ?▒   }▒   r▒              ▒▒   ▒▒   vz?  y?   z▒
▒{?  ]??  ?    ???  ??   ??   ??   ???  4▒   ▒??  ▒y?     ▒??  ▒}?  f??  ▒??  L??                        ?▒   ?▒   Rz?             ?▒   ▒??  W    ▒    ▒
▒??  {?   ???  ???  ???  ??   ??   ???  5▒   ▒??  ▒▒      ▒??  ▒}?  f??  ▒▒   LinuxV11x64NonProd.tar.gz  ▒    ▒??  S??             ?▒   ▒    x??  ▒    ?▒
▒??  }?   ??   ???  ???  ??   ??   ???  9??  ▒??  Agents  ▒??  ▒??  f??  ▒??  logs                       ▒▒   ▒??  ServiceManager  ▒??  ▒▒   X▒   ▒▒   ▒??
▒??  }??  ???  ???  ?    ??   ?    ▒??  a??  ▒??  ▒▒      cz?  ▒??  f??  ▒▒   ▒??                        ?▒   o▒   t▒              ▒??  ?▒   X▒   ▒▒   ▒▒
▒{?  ▒    ???  ???  ???  ??   ??   0▒   A??  ▒??  A▒      d??  e▒   F??  ▒▒   ▒▒                         ▒??  ▒▒   U▒              ▒▒   ▒▒   Xy?  ▒▒   ▒??
```